# Full screen Bootstrap carousel clunky on first two slides

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I've been searching through Stack Overflow and have seen this question come up before, however any answer that I've tried for myself just hasn't worked, so sorry if I'm posting a question that's already been asked before, but I just can't get this to work for some reason!

I am trying to implement a fullscreen bootstrap carousel for a Wordpress homepage, where the slides are background-images set to background-size:cover. The images also need to fade from one to the next. However I'm obviously doing sthg wrong as the first two slides are fading to white, (black in Firefox).

Can anyone help me fix this so that there is a smooth transition?

Thanks.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel container slide carousel-fade">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="active item one">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2><a href="http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-    form/category/work/#astral">Astral Pattern</a></h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item two">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2><a href="http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/category/work/#shark">Imaginary Music - La Shark</a></h2>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item three">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2><a href="http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/category/work/#troubled">Troubled Waters</a></h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"></a><a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">    </a>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.carousel .item {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%; 
height: 100%;
}
.carousel .one {
    background: url('http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/wp-  content/uploads/2016/01/Bunhill-Walking-Map_small.jpg') no-repeat center  center;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .two {
    background: url('http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/wp-   content/uploads/2016/01/Imaginary-Music_small.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .three {
    background: url('http://www.topographicwebdesign.co.uk/work-form/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Sir-Johns-Nose_small.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
}
.carousel .active.left {
    left:0;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:2;
}
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
    background-color:white;
    position:fixed;
    background-image:none;
}
.carousel-caption{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:10px;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-shadow:none;
}
.carousel-control {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.carousel-control.left {
    left:10px;
    right:auto;
    top:50%;
} 
.carousel-control.right {
    right:10px;
    top:50%;
}
a.carousel-control:hover{
    background-color:white;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: .8s;
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  -webkit-transition-duration: .8s;
  -moz-transition-property: opacity;
  -moz-transition-duration: .8s;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
}
```

And here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.carousel').carousel({interval: 5000});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XXQzwR - working good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the slides lying underneath top one aren't yet visible? Does setting display: block and/or visibility: visible on all the .item elements help?

Comment: You're right! Thanks very much, I completely overlooked that.

Comment: Glad I could help! I'm just starting out on here... any chance of an upvote / accepted answer? Thanks!

Comment: thanks Andrew - I tried upvoting you but I'm pretty new too so haven't earned enough reputation points to do that, sorry!

Comment: Ha! No worries... it's a bit of a chicken/egg situation eh?

Comment: There's still a problem in Google Chrome - for some reason during the fade you can kind of see the next image clunkily slide in too. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a URL I could view it at?

Comment: Try setting: left: 0px on your .item class

Comment: Genius! Thanks very much Andrew, much appreciated.

Comment: No problem! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Check your URL on background for classes .one and .two. There are blank space in URL.

Could you post javascript to simulate the transition?

Comment: Thanks, I added the javascript - it now works with Andrew's suggestion of adding display:block to the .item class.

Comment: There's still a problem in Google Chrome - for some reason during the fade you can kind of see the next image clunkily slide in too. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm glad you have found help.